# Unable to Call More than One Meta Box Output

Tags: php, functions, metabox, post-meta

I have a custom meta box with multiple text fields. I use this to call the information in the first box:

```
<?php the_post(); echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'dbt_text', true ); ?>
```

And this to call the second field:

```
<?php the_post(); echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'dbt_text1', true ); ?>
```

**Here's the problem,** when used individually they work perfectly. But if I have both on the same page, only one outputs. I need them to be separate but I need them both to produce their respective outputs from the meta box. I have tried to troubleshoot this and I just don't know enough about PHP and the WP core to figure this out on my own. Help is appreciated!

Here is the code for my custom meta boxes:

```
$prefix = 'dbt_';
$meta_box = array(
    'id' => 'my-meta-box',
    'title' => 'Titles',
    'page' => 'page',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Primary Title',
            'id' => $prefix . 'text',
            'type' => 'text'
            ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Secondary Title',
            'id' => $prefix . 'text1',
            'type' => 'text',   
        )
    )
);

add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_box');
// Add meta box
function mytheme_add_box() {
    global $meta_box;
    add_meta_box($meta_box['id'], $meta_box['title'], 'mytheme_show_box', $meta_box['page'], $meta_box['context'], $meta_box['priority']);
}

// Callback function to show fields in meta box
function mytheme_show_box() {
    global $meta_box, $post;
    // Use nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="mytheme_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';
    echo '<table class="form-table">';
    foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
        // get current post meta data
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
        echo '<tr>',
                '<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
                '<td>';
        switch ($field['type']) {
            case 'text':
                echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" />',
                    '<br />', $field['desc'];
                break;          
        }
        echo    '<td>',
            '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}

add_action('save_post', 'mytheme_save_data');

// Save data from meta box
function mytheme_save_data($post_id) {
    global $meta_box;

    // verify nonce
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['mytheme_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check permissions
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will be like this

```
 if( have_posts() ):
  while( have_posts()): the_post();
    $txt_fld = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'dbt_text', true );
    $txt_fld2 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'dbt_text', true );
  endwhile;
 endif;
```

echo $txt_fld;
echo $txt_fld2

like this way.